# Updating AndroidApp By VersionCode

Tags: android, version, android-manifest

I have an app that gets from a server the current version of a hosted app

And then I compare in my app running the ServerVersion vs the android:versionCode, but

when I change `android:versionCode="1"` at manifest.xml to a different value, 
I get Parse Error  There is a problem parsing the package

Also if I get back "1" at the versionCode the app can be installed again. 
Can someone explain me what's the problem?

Comment: Yes, a higher value :(

Comment: But is a Integer right?

Comment: Yep is an integer I only change by 2 or 3

Comment: Can you post the code?

Comment: What IDE do you use? Android Studio or Eclipse+ADT?